# Python Multi-Threading, append different values to a method

Tags: python, multithreading, flash, sockets

See the code below, "J2".

In the xml j2 as you can see "Y=getY" it's doing that for each id+pproxy(multithreading)
Now what I want is, I want it to continue changing id and k2= but use the same Y for only 3 times.  Then after that get a new Y and do the same..

So for example

```
<j2 Y="one value" id="3 multi threads pass trough" k="3 multi threads"
```

and then after that `<j2 Y="new y value because only 3 ids can pass through one Y" id="same again" k="same again">`

```
j2 = str('<j2 cb="'+rcv.attrib["c"]+'" Y="'+str(Y[0])+'" l5="'+str(Y[1]).strip()+'" l4="583" l3="463" l2="0" q="1" y="'+rcv.attrib['i']+'" k="'+k+'" k3="0" p="0" c="'+str(info[2])+'" f="0" u="'+str(uid)+'" d0="0" n=" " a="0" h="" v="0" />\0')
```

The Y value should be the same while 3 ids pass through it, then when 3 have passed through it, grab a new Y value.

Take a look at this script:

```
import socket, socks
import xml.etree.ElementTree as tree
import time, random, urllib2
import threading
from itertools import izip
def gB(data,first,last):
    x=len(first)
    begin = data.find(first) + x
    end = data.find(last,begin)
    return data[begin:end]
def isInt(buf):
    try:
        i = int(buf)
        return True
    except:
        return False
def ip(roomname):
    if isInt(roomname):
        room = roomname
    else:
        room = gB(urllib2.urlopen('http://xat.com/'+roomname).read(),'FlashVars="id=','&xc=')
    room = int(room)
    x = urllib2.urlopen('http://xat.com/web_gear/chat/ip.htm?'+str(time.time())).read()
    x = tree.fromstring(x)
    xSock = x.attrib['xSock'].split(',')
    rSock = []
    while len(rSock) < 4:
        rSock.append(xSock[len(rSock) * 4 + random.randint(0,1)])
    return rSock[(room & 96) >> 5],int(10007 + (room % 32)),room
def parseID(auser3):
    auser3 = auser3.split('&')
    userid = auser3[1].split('=')[1]
    k1 = auser3[2].split('=')[1]
    k2 = auser3[3].split('=')[1]
    return [userid,k1,k2]
    return l5
def getY(au, p0, p1, p2, p3, yi):
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    sock.settimeout(10)
    sock.connect(("127.0.0.1",1337))
    sock.send(au+"_"+p0+"_"+p1+"_"+p2+"_"+p3+"_"+yi)
    data = sock.recv(1270)
    parse = data.split("\"")
    sock.close()
    print "Y => "+parse[1]+" L5 => "+parse[3]
    return [parse[1], parse[3]]
def raider(a3,p):
    info = ip(chat)
    try:
        socks.setdefaultproxy(socks.PROXY_TYPE_SOCKS4, p[0], int(p[1]))
        socket.test = socks.socksocket
        xat = socket.test(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM, socket.SOL_TCP)
        xat.settimeout(10)
        xat.connect((info[0],int(info[1])))
        xat.send('<y r="'+str(info[2])+'" />\0')
        bypass = xat.recv(1024)
        print "\nRecv --> "+bypass+"\n"
        rcv = tree.fromstring(bypass.strip("\0"))
        if 'i' not in rcv.attrib:
            raise Exception("YUP")
        import pprint
        pprint.pprint(a3)
        uid = a3[0]
        k = a3[1]
        if 'au' in rcv.attrib: 
            Y = getY(rcv.attrib["au"], rcv.attrib["p"].split("_")[0],rcv.attrib["p"].split("_")[1],rcv.attrib["p"].split("_")[2],rcv.attrib["p"].split("_")[3], rcv.attrib["i"])
            j2 = str('<j2 cb="'+rcv.attrib["c"]+'" Y="'+str(Y[0])+'" l5="'+str(Y[1]).strip()+'" l4="583" l3="463" l2="0" q="1" y="'+rcv.attrib['i']+'" k="'+k+'" k3="0" p="0" c="'+str(info[2])+'" f="0" u="'+str(uid)+'" d0="0" n=" " a="0" h="" v="0" />\0')
            xat.send(j2)
            print "\nSend [Bypass] --> "+j2+"\n"
        else:
            Y = getY(str(0), rcv.attrib["p"].split("_")[0],rcv.attrib["p"].split("_")[1],rcv.attrib["p"].split("_")[2],rcv.attrib["p"].split("_")[3], rcv.attrib["i"])
            j2 = str('<j2 cb="'+rcv.attrib["c"]+'" l5="'+str(Y[1]).strip()+'" l4="583" l3="463" l2="0" q="1" y="'+rcv.attrib['i']+'" k="'+k+'" k3="0" p="0" c="'+str(info[2])+'" f="0" u="'+str(uid)+'" d0="0" n=" " a="0" h="" v="0" />\0')
            xat.send(j2)
            print "\nSend --> "+j2+"\n"
        while 1:
            time.sleep(1)
            xat.send('<m t="   | XAT IS CORRUPT |   " u="'+uid+'" />\0')
    except:
        pass
chat = raw_input("Chat to raid: ")
ids = [i.strip() for i in open('ids.txt','r')]
proxies = [i.strip() for i in open('socks.txt','r')]
for (i,j) in izip(ids,proxies):
    i = parseID(i)
    j = j.split(':')
    threading.Thread(target=raider,args=(i,j)).start()
```

Comment: I had a look at the script but I do not understand. Could you tell me what you expect and what happens that differs from what you expect? Best way to show this with code and output.

Comment: The u-"id" in the j2 should change but the Y= should remain the same 3 times and then grab a new one via getY